# How can I validate a Guice scope's usage in tests?

Tags: java, guice, guice-3

I have some tests that I would like to have fail if certain Guice scopes are used incorrectly.  For example, a `@Singleton` should not have any `@RequestScoped` or `@TestScoped` dependencies (`Provider<>`s are okay, of course).

In production, this is partially solved because eagerly-bound singletons will be constructed before the scope is entered, resulting in `OutOfScopeException`s.  But in development, the singleton will be created lazily while inside the scope, and no problems are evident.

Judging by [these](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=11) [two](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=127) open issues, it seems like there is no easy, built-in way to do this.  Can I achieve this using the SPI?  I tried using a `TypeListener` but it's not clear how to get the dependencies of a given type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I've accomplished this with the 4.0 beta of Guice, using `ProvisionListener`. I tried `TypeListener` but it seems that `TypeListener`s get called before Guice necessarily has bindings for that type's dependencies.  This caused exceptions, and even a deadlock in one case.

```
private static class ScopeValidator implements ProvisionListener {
    private @Inject Injector injector;
    private @Inject WhateverScope scope;

    @Override
    public <T> void onProvision(ProvisionInvocation<T> provision) {
        if (injector == null) {
            // The injector isn't created yet, just return. This isn't a
            // problem because any scope violations will be caught by
            // WhateverScope itself here (throwing an OutOfScopeException)
            return;
        }

        Binding<?> binding = provision.getBinding();
        Key<?> key = binding.getKey();

        if (Scopes.isSingleton(binding) && binding instanceof HasDependencies) {
            Set<Dependency<?>> dependencies = ((HasDependencies) binding).getDependencies();

            for (Dependency<?> dependency : dependencies) {
                Key<?> dependencyKey = dependency.getKey();
                Binding<?> dependencyBinding = injector.getExistingBinding(dependencyKey);

                if (dependencyBinding != null && Scopes.isScoped(dependencyBinding, whateverScope, WhateverScoped.class)) {
                    throw new ProvisionException(String.format(
                            "Singleton %s depends on @WhateverScoped %s",
                            key, dependencyKey));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is not a trivial problem, but definitely it is a good question! There could be a tester for scope binding problems you mentioned. I think i could make a Junit runner to generate warning with wrong binding practice. I will update this post later with it.

For now there is a example how to get binding scopes.

**Module**

```
public class ScopeTestModel extends ServletModule {

  @Override
  protected void configureServlets() {
    super
        .configureServlets();
    bind(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("REQ1"))).to(Object.class).in(ServletScopes.REQUEST);
    bind(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("REQ2"))).to(RequestScopedObject.class);

    bind(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("SINGLETON1"))).to(Object.class).asEagerSingleton();
    bind(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("SINGLETON2"))).to(Object.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    bind(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("SINGLETON3"))).to(SingletonScopedObject.class);

    bind(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("SESS1"))).to(Object.class).in(ServletScopes.SESSION);
    bind(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("SESS2"))).to(SessionScopedObject.class);
  }
}
```

**TestCase**

```
public class TestScopeBinding {

  private Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ScopeTestModel());

  @Test
  public void testRequestScope() throws Exception {
    Binding<Object> req1 = injector.getBinding(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("REQ1")));
    Binding<Object> req2 = injector.getBinding(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("REQ2")));

    Scope scope1 = getScopeInstanceOrNull(req1);
    Scope scope2 = getScopeInstanceOrNull(req2);

    Assert.assertEquals(ServletScopes.REQUEST,scope1);
    Assert.assertEquals(ServletScopes.REQUEST,scope2);
  }

  @Test
  public void testSessionScope() throws Exception {
    injector.getAllBindings();
    Binding<Object> sess1 = injector.getBinding(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("SESS1")));
    Binding<Object> sess2 = injector.getBinding(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("SESS2")));

    Scope scope1 = getScopeInstanceOrNull(sess1);
    Scope scope2 = getScopeInstanceOrNull(sess2);

    Assert.assertEquals(ServletScopes.SESSION,scope1);
    Assert.assertEquals(ServletScopes.SESSION,scope2);
  }

  @Test
  public void testSingletonScope() throws Exception {
    injector.getAllBindings();
    Binding<Object> sng1 = injector.getBinding(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("SINGLETON1")));
    Binding<Object> sng2 = injector.getBinding(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("SINGLETON2")));
    Binding<Object> sng3 = injector.getBinding(Key.get(Object.class, Names.named("SINGLETON3")));

    Scope scope1 = getScopeInstanceOrNull(sng1);
    Scope scope2 = getScopeInstanceOrNull(sng2);
    Scope scope3 = getScopeInstanceOrNull(sng3);

    Assert.assertEquals(Scopes.SINGLETON,scope1);
    Assert.assertEquals(Scopes.SINGLETON,scope2);
    Assert.assertEquals(Scopes.SINGLETON,scope3);
  }

  private Scope getScopeInstanceOrNull(final Binding<?> binding) {
    return binding.acceptScopingVisitor(new DefaultBindingScopingVisitor<Scope>() {

      @Override
      public Scope visitScopeAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation> scopeAnnotation) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("I don't know how to handle the scopeAnnotation: %s",scopeAnnotation.getCanonicalName()));
      }

      @Override
      public Scope visitNoScoping() {
          if(binding instanceof LinkedKeyBinding) {
            Binding<?> childBinding = injector.getBinding(((LinkedKeyBinding)binding).getLinkedKey());
            return getScopeInstanceOrNull(childBinding);
          }
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public Scope visitEagerSingleton() {
        return Scopes.SINGLETON;
      }

      public Scope visitScope(Scope scope) {
        return scope;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Scoped objects**

```
@RequestScoped
public class RequestScopedObject extends Object {

}

@SessionScoped
public class SessionScopedObject extends Object {

}

@Singleton
public class SingletonScopedObject extends Object {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly a piece of the puzzle.  For testing whether a binding is a singleton or not, there's also `Scopes.isSingleton()`.  The other part of the puzzle is where I was stuck.  I've found a Guice 4 solution that I'm about to post, but I'd still like a Guice 3 solution if possible.